# How to keep only Latest "N" number of files/objects in S3 bucket periodically using bash script or any other methods

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

I am using S3 bucket to store my web application log files. 
Now I need to know is there any option available, to keep the latest 20 files only, regardless when they are created. I can't use S3 auto expiry option as I always need the latest 20 files inside my bucket.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this answer will solve your problem

```
aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket/ --recursive | sort -k1 | sort -k2 | head -n -30 | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | while read -r line ; do  
echo "Removing \"${line}\"";                                                                      
    aws s3 rm "s3://your-bucket/${line}";              
done
```

For more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373909/16885246

Comment: shouldn't this just be a setting on AWS??

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:-**

a) Use S3 Notification Service and trigger lambda for each Put object in S3

---

b) list the objects in bucket using python boto sdk and store the values(key,date modified) in list .

---

c) sort the list by date/time and delete the old record data 21st data.

**Option 2:-**

a) Configure SQS in notification service and trigger lambda for each put object.

---

b) Schedule a lambda service based on your requirements.

---

c) list the objects in bucket using python boto sdk and store the values(key,date modified) in list .

---

d) Sort the list by date/time and delete the old record data 21st data.

Based on your requirements you need to choose the option 1 (or) option 2.

If your file write/read/download in S3 bucket are time intensive operation choose option 1
If your file write/read/download are not time intensive operation choose option 2.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach would be enabling [S3 bucket versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html) and uploading log files under the same object name. Then a [bucket lifecycle configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html) can be created which will retain only 20 non-current versions of this object.

This way all the versioning & object deletion is offloaded to AWS, eliminating the need for a lambda with custom logic.

Here's a Terraform implementation for the described solution:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "backup_bucket_lifecycle" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.backup.id
  rule {
    id     = "maintain_only_20_versions_of_all_objects"
    status = "Enabled"
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days           = 1
      newer_noncurrent_versions = 20
    }
  }
}
```